# Full calendar not display correct date time in week and day view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have this full calendar code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
       $.ajax({
         url: baseUrl+"events",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(doc) {
           var events = [];
           $(doc).each(function() {   
           events.push({
               id: $(this).attr('id'),
               title: $(this).attr('title'),
               description: "Start time :"+$(this).attr('start')+"End Time:"+$(this).attr('end'),
               start: $(this).attr('start'), 
               end_time: $(this).attr('end'),
             });
           });
          callback(events);
         }
       });
     },  eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
       
         var startDate =  moment(eventObj.start).format('DD MMM, Y hh:mm A'); 
         var endDate =  eventObj.end_time ? moment(eventObj.end_time).format('DD MMM,Y hh:mm A') : '-'; 
         var contentsHtml = '<div class="t2f_popover_event"><ul>';
          contentsHtml = contentsHtml+ '<li> <b>Start Time: </b>'+ startDate+'</li><li> <b>End Time: </b>'+endDate+'</li><li><b>Event Type:</b>'+(' Working hours')+'</li>';
         '</ul> </div>';  
   
         $el.popover({
           title: '<div style="color:#fff; text-transform:capitalize;font-weight: 600;padding:5px;">'+eventObj.title+'</div>',
           content: eventObj.description,
           trigger: 'manual',
           placement: 'left',
           container: 'body',
          content: contentsHtml,
           html: true
         }).on("mouseenter", function () {
             ...
             ...
       });
       },
     eventOverlap : false,
       header: {
         left: 'prev,next today',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
         },
         changeView : 'agendaDay',
         defaultDate: new Date(),
         navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
         selectable: true,
         selectHelper: true,
         selectConstraint: {
           start: jQuery.fullCalendar.moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
           end: jQuery.fullCalendar.moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'month')
         },
         displayEventTime: false,
         disableDragging: true,
         editable: false,
         eventLimit: true, 
       });
  
   });
```

> Start time is -   2022-12-03T01:00:00 i.e 1:00 AM
>
> End time is   -   2022-12-03T11:59:00 i.e 11:59 AM

but on calendar time is not proper of each event.

[image]

it should be from `1:00 AM` to `11:59 AM` but in calendar event start from `1:00 AM`.

Any Solution to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: `end_time: $(this).attr('end')` needs to be `end: $(this).attr('end')`. Read the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object) more carefully. FullCalendar isn't recognising your end date because you named the property wrong, therefore you event just gets the [default duration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/defaultTimedEventDuration) instead.

Comment: P.S. Why are you using such an old version of fullCalendar? V5 has many more features, better performance, and bug fixes.

Comment: I had the same problem. I just added `timezone: 'local',` as option in fullcalendar function and my issue solved. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: @Kamlesh did you post that on the right question? Because that would not be a solution to the specific issue the OP raised here. Their problem was an incorrectly named event property...changing the timezone would not fix that. Also, if you do have a genuine solution to any question, please post it below as an Answer, then it's searchable and voteable and so on. Thanks.